# Restricted Flow Of Power

Tags: google, pagerank, sitelinks

I'm sure all is fine, but i need some reassurance.

Last month my company launched consolidated two of their websites into one new website.

www.fdmgroup.com and www.fdmacademy.com into a newly designed www.fdmgroup.com.

Because the FDM Academy grew as it's own brand we decided not to just forward the domain to the fdmgroup website, but instead just mirror the new FDM Group website and use a canonical tags to the FDM Group domain (so the link juice will pass to the FDM Group domain pages)

The website has be live for nearly a month and i don't believe any power has passed down through the FDM Group website to it's deeper pages even though 301 redirects from the legacy group and academy domains in place.

I am also seeing the same problem on the FDM Academy domain, but i expect to see this as every page has a canonical to the same page on the

**Is there anything which is restricting the flow of power through the site, or am i just being impatient?**

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know; canonical tag will not pass the power of link juice. Canonical tag is useful when you are publishing same content on multiple location of the same website or different website.

For example: if you mirrored www.fdmacademy.com on fdmgroup and placed canonical tag on respective page of fdmgroup that stats the original source of that content is respective page on fdmacademy website. Search engine will not give penalize fdmgroup for placing duplicate content and will not give any weight to that particular page.

Now; if you want to pass the link juice to mirrored pages on fdmgroup website; i strongly recommend implementing 301 (permanent) redirection from Fdmacademy to fdmgroup pages.

Hope it will help !!

Comment: Yes, even google considers 301 redirects as a better solution whenever it's possible than the canonical tag in the head. And considering the relevance of headers, makes sense.

Comment: thats true PatomasS, it is always advisable to redirect pages which are not important.